# Only my home wifi is grayed out in ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: wireless, networking

When I was setting up Ubuntu (for the first time) on my netbook running XP, I decided to skip the network set up initially. Now I can connect to all my neighbors wifi networks, but my home network is grayed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the home network, then reinstall it manually, specifying the name, the security type and password.